# How to download the Enthought Tool Suite python script?

Tags: python, ets

I have Python downloaded already, but want to contribute code to the Enthought Tool Suite (ETS).  According to this site (http://code.enthought.com/source/):

it says to download the following python script: https://raw.github.com/enthought/ets/master/ets.py

I put the ets.py into the python script, save as...and in the Python Shell, I typed in "import ets"

However, nothing happens.

Also, the site says to run the following commands:

```
$ mkdir ets

$ cd ets   # and copy ets.py here

$ python ets.py clone
```

Typing those lines in Python Shell gives me the message: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

As you can see, I'm new to Python, and I don't know what I'm doing.  How do I download the ETS script and run the commands??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those last commands aren't meant to be entered into the Python console, they're meant to be entered at the terminal shell.

```
localhost-2:tmp $ mkdir ets
localhost-2:tmp $ cd ets
localhost-2:ets $ cp ../ets.py .
```

This last command assumes that ets.py was in the original directory.  Now we can run it [edit: make sure you have `git` installed, or this won't work]:

```
localhost-2:ets $ python ets.py clone
Cloning package encore
URL: https://github.com/enthought/encore.git
Cloning into encore...
remote: Counting objects: 1081, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (483/483), done.
remote: Total 1081 (delta 729), reused 942 (delta 592)
Receiving objects: 100% (1081/1081), 981.12 KiB | 1.80 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (729/729), done.

Cloning package traits
URL: https://github.com/enthought/traits.git
Cloning into traits...

[etc.]

Cloning package etsproxy
URL: https://github.com/enthought/etsproxy.git
Cloning into etsproxy...
remote: Counting objects: 3577, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2243/2243), done.
remote: Total 3577 (delta 1053), reused 3571 (delta 1047)
Receiving objects: 100% (3577/3577), 369.81 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1053/1053), done.
```

After this, you need to install everything (this will look different depending on your operating system):

```
localhost-2:ets $ python ets.py develop
Running command ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python', 'setup.py', 'develop'] in package encore
running develop
running egg_info
creating encore.egg-info
writing encore.egg-info/PKG-INFO

[long build process removed]
```